# Dynamically choose whether to use __slots__ in a class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I've got a generic container class:

```
from typing import Container, Generic, TypeVar, NamedTuple
import sys


fixed_typing = (sys.version_info >= (3, 6, 2) or 
                (3, 5, 3) <= sys.version_info < (3, 6))
T = TypeVar("T")
_Interval = NamedTuple("_Interval", [("start", int),
                                     ("stop", int),
                                     ("data", T)])

class Interval(_Interval, Container, Generic[T]):

    if fixed_typing:
        __slots__ = ()

    ...
```

As you might've noticed there is a switch controlling the usage of `__slots__` during class initialisation. Basically, I'd like to use slots whenever possible, but older versions of the `typing` module do not support slots in generic classes due to a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue31272). Is it okay to use the switch from the code design perspective? I've never seen it before, that's why I'm wondering. I find it similar to checking compiler flags using the preprocessor in C/C++, which is a common thing to do.

Comment: Can you explain specifically what you mean by "okay" in this context?

Comment: @RobertHarvey 1. is it Pythonic; 2. can it cause any headache in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the one hand, this both works and does what it says it does.  So you're already ahead of a substantial amount of real-world code on that front.

On the other hand, are you going to add extra branches like this for every bug they fix in Python?  It's probably not worth it, frankly.  Most users who are running 3.5.x, for example, should have 3.5.3+, or else their distributors should have backported this and other bug fixes.  If someone complains that your code does not run on 3.5.2, it is entirely reasonable to point them to the Python bug.  If you do not want to field those complaints in the first place, you can add a version check at your program's entry point and fail-fast there with a sensible error message.  Given that some distributors may be manually backporting fixes to old versions of Python, this may or may not be an ideal design decision, depending on your target audience and platform (for example, Windows users will typically be using a "stock" version of Python, while Linux users are more likely to get Python from their distro's package repository).

On the third hand, why do you need `__slots__` in the first place?  In most cases, you don't.  In most of the cases where you do need it, you can't just yank it out to work around a bug.  So why is it there at all?

On the *fourth* hand, based on the name of your class and its variables, you appear to be re-implementing `range()`, which [already has a fast `__contains__()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30081275/1340389).  What really confuses me, though, is this `data` variable.  It looks like you are trying to bundle a `range()` together with some arbitrary object.  If so, you probably want composition rather than inheritance.  But either way, that's a poor choice of name.

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, enforcing a correct version is not an option (I've tried).

Comment: @EliKorvigo: Only you can evaluate your precise situation and target audience, but I would encourage you to carefully consider the distribution of responsibility.  It sounds like you are saying that 1) you are responsible for making your software work on the customer's system, but 2) you are not allowed to update Python on the customer's system, even [within a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one), and yet 3) the customer is not a Python 2.7 holdout.  If all those are true, you have my sympathy.

Comment: 2. I need `__slots__`, because of memory concerns – there are going to be hundreds of thousands of these objects (basically, I use `__slots__` to compensate a little for the switch from C/Cython to pure Python, which was all for the generic type annotations); 3. `__contains__` is implemented differently (it checks for `data`), the naming convention (including attribute names) deliberately mirrors that of Python's `range`.

Comment: @EliKorvigo: There is no `data` attribute in a `range` object.

Comment: I know. That attribute was added to store annotation (this objects are supposed to live in an AVL-tree, representing annotation).

Comment: I agree, that it's better to use composition instead of inheritance. This code was initially a fork of the [intervaltree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) package, which I have to reimplement due to performance issues. The inheritance was "inherited" straight from that package..

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty reasonable to expect people to upgrade their version of python to the latest of the same minor release. For example, telling people to upgrade from 3.5.3 to 3.5.4 or from 3.6.1 to 3.6.2. In that case I'd do something like:

```
assert (sys.version_info >= (3, 6, 2) or 
                (3, 5, 3) <= sys.version_info < (3, 6)), "Your version of python is buggy! Please upgrade!"
```